# how to build ionic project apk without internet connection on windows

Tags: android, build, ionic-framework, offline

im wondering if there is a way to build ionic android application without internet? Ive search so far but i havent seen anything. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which part of the process that requires internet are you talking about?

Comment: The project buildind, the création of the apk. It requires internet with ionic lab

Comment: The app creation will aways require internet if you use the ionic commands, because ionic downloads an git repository as a project starter. If you maintain a base initial project, and copy it when starting a new app, you can then test it offline.

Comment: About the android building, the needed api's are download on demand if you dont have them. This should be solved by running the build proccess at least once, or opening the sdk manager and downloading all dependencies at once.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers, its clearer now. But what do you mean by maintaining a base initial project? Where can i find the sdk manager for ionic projects?

Comment: I meant downloading this repository and copying it when needed https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs (but do it using the ionic command for the first time since will download the remaining dependencies)

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this as soon as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I have experienced till now. Ionic uses gradle for android build. It first time downloads all the dependencies from internet. So internet is most for first gradle build but it caches them and no internet is needed for further build.Since you are having problem why don't you globally update your cordova and ionic.

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Comment: I can build the android app offline if i do the update?

Comment: I don't mean that. I have been building android app offline for long. Internet connection is needed for first time and if there are new dependencies but not each time. If you are not achieving this may be why don't you update all your packages.